# Read JSON files from multiple line file in spark scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I'm learning spark in Scala. I have a JSON file as follows:

```
[
  {
    "name": "ali",
    "age": "13",
    "phone": "09123455737",
    "sex": "m"
  },{
    "name": "amir",
    "age": "24",
    "phone": "09123475737",
    "sex": "m"
  }
]
```

and there is just this code:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val jsonFile = sqlContext.read.json("path-to-json-file")
```

I just receive `corrupted_row : String` nothing else
but when put every person(or objects) in single row, code works fine

How can I read from multiple lines for a JSON sqlContext in spark?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to read it into an RDD yourself and then convert it to a Dataset:

```
spark.read.json(sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(...).values)
```

Comment: so there is no better way. it's hard to do it in complex json structures, but thank you

Comment: You should be able to use an already built parser (play-json, json4s, etc) to get it into rows of strings, which is all you really need as the `read.json(RDD)` will do the type work for you.

Comment: @JustinPihony Why not simply `json(sc.wholeTextFiles(...).values)`?

Comment: @zero323 That wouldn't parse them. You could do `.values.map(...parse...)`, but I think I'd prefer collect..more stylistic than anything else

Comment: Are you sure? As far as I remember it should parse.

Comment: That's great. It is not much but one less thing to write from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is getting caused because you have multiline json row. Although by default spark.read.json expect a row to be in a single line but this is configurable:

You can set option `spark.read.json("path-to-json-file").option("multiLine", true)`